# How to remove the shadow

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to get a very specific border going. Using `\tcolorbox`, I'm now close, but have some problems. Specifically:

- There is a shadow that I want to remove
- For some reason the text is gray, not black

Reading through [the manual](http://ctan.mirror.ac.za/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) I know there is a "no shadow" option, but lacking any example I am unable to put it to use. In the MWE below I have tried adding "no shadow" to the list of options but I get this error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key `/tcb/noshadow` and I
>   am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Just to clarify, I do NOT want a border/shadow on the bottom or right hand side. I do want a (very wide) border on the left and a normal border on the top.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{leftrule=5pt, toprule=.5pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, colback=white, notitle, sharp corners, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{topbot}
\subsection*{This is the title}
\end{topbot}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Here is a zoomed in screenshot that shows the color problem and the shadow at the bottom of the box:

[image: zoomed in image]

Here is another screenshot of the solution proposed by AboAmmar:

[image: still a shadow]

Comment: Did you try `\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{leftrule=5pt, toprule=.5pt, rightrule=-0.1pt, bottomrule=-0.1pt, colback=white, notitle, sharp corners, #1}`

Comment: @Ubiquitous still the same

Comment: For `no shadow` try with `\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{enhanced, no shadow, left....`. And load the package with `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any phantom rules, but this could be an alternative solution. It uses an `empty` skin which doesn't draw any frame or background but keeps all margins. After that two `borderline`s can be used to draw the desired frame.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{empty, notitle, sharp corners, borderline north={1pt}{0pt}{black},
borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{black},
#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{topbot}
\subsection*{This is the title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{topbot}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no shadow, it is that `leftrule` that you have specified `5pt` in width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{topbot}[1][]{leftrule=5pt, toprule=.5pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, colback=white, notitle, sharp corners, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{topbot}
\subsection*{This is the title}
\end{topbot}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this still gives a border for me. See updated question.

Comment: Also, I _do_ want the wide border on the left. I just don't want any border or shadow on the bottom or right hand side.

Comment: I just tried your code. There is definitively no shadow. What LaTeX engine do you use?

Comment: The tiny rule that you sometimes see is merely a viewer issue. The PDF viewer at some values of zoom makes that line visible, but this is not found in print.

Comment: @AboAmmar. This is surprising. I can't see a reason why the viewer would show a line which does not exist at all. Mine does not show any line at any zoom level. I suspect that the code which produces the picture above is not excatly the one given in the mwe.

Comment: @EricDomenjoud - The line is a TikZ path which is drawn anyway, it exists, just the thickness is 0pt. And the gray shadow is just a TikZ fill effect.

Comment: @AboAmmar. I just checked the pdf. The frame is actually drawn by means of a large black rectangle with a white rectangle above it containing the title. So you are partially right. There is no 0pt width rule but it is a matter of placement of the white rectangle. If it is not completely accurate, the viewer may let a thin black line appear.

Comment: @EricDomenjoud  -That is exactly what I meant, when I said _fill effect_  I meant those two rectangles (one gray and one white) because only a closed path can be filled.

Comment: Interesting to know this. But unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem yet. This is not for print but rather for digital use, so it should look the same in all viewers, without any line. Are there any alternatives? Or should I move away from using tcolorbox?